# Find elements between date and time intervals MySQL

Tags: sql, database, date, time

How do I query a SQL Database to search trough a date and time interval when I have different columns for date and time ?

```
SELECT  * FROM prices.prices WHERE data BETWEEN CAST('2020-01-06' AS DATE) AND CAST(Var3 >='12:41' AS TIME) AND CAST('2020-01-10' AS DATE) AND CAST(Var3 <= '14:59' AS TIME);
```

This above doesnt work...

Where Var3 is the time column and data is the date column

Comment: Please share sample data and expected result

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work? The result is not as expected?

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of the column 'data' is date, no need to use cast function anymore

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    prices
WHERE
    (data >= '2020-01-06' AND var3 >= (CAST('12:41' as time))) AND
    (data <= '2020-01-10' AND <= (CAST(Var3 '14:59' as time)))
```

Try this out. Not sure is what you want, cause your question didn't make it clear

Comment: I made like this and it worked: